# Multiplying a 2d array with each slice of 3d array - Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication, lapack

I am looking for an optimized way of computing a element wise multiplication of a 2d array by each slice of a 3d array (using numpy).

for example:

`w = np.array([[1,5], [4,9], [12,15]])
y = np.ones((3,2,3))`

I want to get a result as a 3d array with the same shape as `y`.

Broadcasting using the * operator is not allowed.
In my case, the third dimensions is very long and a for loop is not convenient.

Comment: `z = np.einsum('ij,ijk->ijk',w,y)` does the job !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given arrays

```
import numpy as np

w = np.array([[1,5], [4,9], [12,15]])

print(w)

[[ 1  5]
 [ 4  9]
 [12 15]]
```

and

```
y = np.ones((3,2,3))

print(y)

[[[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]]
```

We can multiple the arrays directly,

```
z = ( y.transpose() * w.transpose() ).transpose()

print(z)

[[[  1.   1.   1.]
  [  5.   5.   5.]]

 [[  4.   4.   4.]
  [  9.   9.   9.]]

 [[ 12.  12.  12.]
  [ 15.  15.  15.]]]
```

We might note that this produces the same result as np.einsum('ij,ijk->ijk',w,y), perhaps with a little less effort and overhead.

Comment: What you see in the answer, was copied from my screen.  I just tried it again to confirm.  Please try creating a fresh program file and insert just those four lines of code (or seven with the print statements)

Comment: yes it works on this example, but when i use it in my computation it raises an error (it cannot broadcast on the third dimensionn when its length is not equal to the length of the first dim/...). Anyway, thank you !

Comment: You're right, I fixed it,  missed a transpose on the y array.   It now generalizes to any number > 0 in the third dimension

Comment: A note of caution,  when working with sufficiently large arrays, be careful about generating a lot of cache misses and check timing.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but with matrix multiplication instead of element-wise multiplication?

Comment: The einsum notation for matrix multiplication of a 2d array on each slice of a 3d array is `np.einsum("ij,jkl->ikl", a, b)`